# How to install net core in amazon linux ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, .net-core, amazon-linux

I am trying to install net core in amazon linux and when I run:

```
#sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.0
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Package: dotnet-runtime-deps-3.0-3.0.0-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
           Requires: openssl-libs
```

Help me! please

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/930.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz !

Comment: @CarlosE.I.Principe Are you able to solve this ?

Comment: Yes, see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-linux-x64-binaries